# Macros in C for getting/setting entries of an array

Tags: c, macros

The small code below inputs a matrix with row-major ordering and two columns. As I understand it, the macro I have included will allow me to access the entries of the array in a more natural way (starting with 1-indexing).

```
#define Alocal(i,j) Alocal[ (j-1) + 2*(i-1) ]

void test_function(double* Alocal)
{

    double a;
    double b;

    /* get first and second entries of the array */
    a = Alocal(1,1);
    b = Alocal(1,2);

}
```

Now I have two questions:
1) Say I pass an integer `Ncols` into the function. Can this be used in the macro for a more general definition? Like

```
#define Alocal(i,j) Alocal[ (j-1) + Ncols*(i-1) ]
```

2) Is there a way to define setting a particular entry of the array to some number in the macros? Like

```
double d;

d = 3.4579;

Alocal(2,2) = d;
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Macro tips

- Wrap macro parameters (which could be expressions) in parentheses, to avoid errors caused by operator precedence.
- Don't 'shadow' variables and other names
- In your case, one should prefer an extra argument for the array for expressive code and reusability of these macros
- A macro name should be all caps by convention
- To isolate the macro expression (similar to how a function 'returning' `void` would do it), you can put at least the `MY_ARRAY_SET` macro into a `do{ ... }while(0)` block.
- If possible, one should instead implement regular functions (they could be inlined aswell)... less error prone, less tinkering, type safe

#### Example

I didn't pay special attention to your index calculation, see [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20083555/1175253)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MY_ARRAY_GET(array,i,j) ( (array)[ ((j)-1) + 2*((i)-1) ] )
#define MY_ARRAY_SET(array,i,j,x) ( (array)[ ((j)-1) + 2*((i)-1) ] = (x) )

void test_function(double* Alocal)
{
    double a;
    double b;

    /* get first and second entries of the array */
    a = MY_ARRAY_GET(Alocal, 1, 1);
    b = MY_ARRAY_GET(Alocal, 1, 2);

    MY_ARRAY_SET(Alocal, 1, 2, 42.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double array[16] =
    { 1.0, 2.0 }; //Initialize to 1.0,2.0,0.0 ...

    test_function(array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Example 2

Tried to put the ideas in other answers & comments together (VLAs and assertions).
Disclaimer: This is a proof of concept, rather than how I would write productive code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

//********************************************************************************
//Utility macros

/**
 * @brief           Internal macros to retrieve the dynamic size of a VLA dimension 1
 * @param   vla     A pointer to the VLA is need in order to properly deduce its dimensions
 * @warning         for internal use only
 */
#define INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D1(vla) (sizeof((*vla))/sizeof((*vla)[0]))

/**
 * @brief           Internal macros to retrieve the dynamic size of a VLA dimension 2
 * @param   vla     A pointer to the VLA is need in order to properly deduce its dimensions
 * @warning         for internal use only
 */
#define INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D2(vla) (sizeof((*vla)[0])/sizeof((*vla)[0][0]))

//********************************************************************************
//Debug check helper

int is_valid_index_2D(const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, const size_t row, const size_t col)
{
    return (nrows) && (ncols) && ((size_t) (row) < (size_t) (nrows)) && ((size_t) (col) < (size_t) (ncols));
}

//********************************************************************************
//1 based index loop macros

#define FOR_RANGE(type,var,start,end) \
        for(type var = (start);var <= (end);++var)

#define FOR(type,var,count) \
        FOR_RANGE(type,var,1,count)

#define MAT_FOREACH_INDEX(rowvar,colvar,mat) \
        FOR(size_t,rowvar,INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D1(&(mat))) \
        FOR(size_t,colvar,INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D2(&(mat)))

//********************************************************************************
//Matrix functions
//Note: These functions rely upon compiler warnings or errors regarding incompatible pointer types
//      (i.E. for a wrong number of array dimensions)

void mat_set(const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, double (* const matrix)[nrows][ncols], const size_t row, const size_t col, const double value)
{
    assert(is_valid_index_2D(nrows,ncols,row,col));
    (*matrix)[row][col] = value;
}

double mat_get(const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, double (* const matrix)[nrows][ncols], const size_t row, const size_t col)
{
    assert(is_valid_index_2D(nrows,ncols,row,col));
    return (*matrix)[row][col];
}

void mat_identity(const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, double (* const matrix)[nrows][ncols], double value)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < nrows; ++row)
        for (int col = 0; col < ncols; ++col)
            (*matrix)[row][col] = row == col ? value : 0.0;
}

void mat_fprintf(FILE* stream, const char* const field_delim, const char* const field_format, const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, double (* const matrix)[nrows][ncols])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < nrows; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < ncols; ++col)
        {
            if (col)
                fputs(field_delim, stream);
            fprintf(stream, "%.2f", (*matrix)[row][col]);
        }
        fprintf(stream, "\n"); //write a line break, the portable way
    }
}

//Matrix utility macros, using 1 based indices
#define MAT_SET(mat,row,col,value) \
        mat_set(INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D1(&(mat)),INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D2(&(mat)),(&(mat)),(row)-1,(col)-1,value)

#define MAT_GET(mat,row,col) \
        mat_get(INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D1(&(mat)),INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D2(&(mat)),(&(mat)),(row)-1,(col)-1)

#define MAT_SET_IDENTIY(mat,value) \
        mat_identity(INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D1(&(mat)),INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D2(&(mat)),(&(mat)),value)

#define MAT_FPRINTF(stream,field_delim,field_format,mat) \
        mat_fprintf((stream),(field_delim),(field_format),INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D1(&(mat)),INTERNAL_VLA_SIZE_D2(&(mat)),(&(mat)))

#define MAT_PRINTF(field_delim,field_format,mat) \
        MAT_FPRINTF(stdout,(field_delim),(field_format),(mat))

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "assertions disabled\n");
#else
    fprintf(stdout, "assertions enabled\n");
#endif

//Note: since below VLA is created on stack, we must be cautious about its size
    for (size_t nrows = 1; nrows <= 5; ++nrows)
    {
        for (size_t ncols = 1; ncols <= 5; ++ncols)
        {

//Allocate the matrix on stack
            double matrix[nrows][ncols];

//Initialize matrix to identity
            MAT_SET_IDENTIY(matrix, 1.0);

            puts("****************************************");
//Print the matrix using a wrapped function
            MAT_PRINTF(", ", "%.2f", matrix);

            puts("****************************************");
//Print the matrix using nested loops with 1 based indices
            FOR(size_t,row,nrows)
                FOR(size_t,col,ncols)
                {
                    printf("%.2f", MAT_GET(matrix, row, col));
                    if (col < ncols)
                        printf(", ");
                    else
                        printf("\n");
                }

            puts("****************************************");
//Print the matrix using a 2D foreach with 1 based indices
            MAT_FOREACH_INDEX(row, col, matrix)
            {
                printf("%.2f", MAT_GET(matrix, row, col));
                if (col < ncols)
                    printf(", ");
                else
                    printf("\n");
            }

        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: +1 for useful tips, however be careful with `#include <cstdlib>` because the question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: Another suggestion that goes with this design is to use a struct that contains a pointer to allocated memory and the sizes of the rows and columns. That lets you do dynamic sized arrays and the macros or inlined functions can check array bounds in debug builds.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you've said should work fine. Just make sure that you have `Ncols` defined, either as a macro, or as a variable.

This works, since your macro simply creates a reference to an element of the original array, and when the code runs, using addition like `test[1+2]` would the same thing as `test[3]`.

As a result, both getting and setting an element will work the same way as if you had hard-coded the array lookup instead of using your macro. So, just to give another example: `Alocal(2,2) = d` will effectively mean (once you've done the subtraction and multiplication, and assuming `NCol` is 2): `Alocal[3] = d`, which is perfectly normal C.

Also, as a side-note, you could also use a multi-dimensional array if you know how many columns the array will need beforehand, which, assuming a two-dimensional array, would make your macro look more like this:

```
#define Alocal(i,j) Alocal[ (j-1) ][ (i-1) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is handled by builtin language features, so you shouldn't use a macro for that.

C, since 1999, has *variable length arrays*, VLA, that perfectly serve the job. Change your prototype to

```
void test_function(size_t ncol, double (*A)[ncol]);
```

Then your compiler will well know how to do an index calculation of something like `A[i][j]` all by itself.

In the above prototype the important thing is to have `ncol` before `A`, such that it is known at the point of the parameter declaration of `A`.

Comment: This won't let him start his array at 1 though.

Comment: +1. Perhaps, one could wrap such C99 functions with simple macros, which would handle the 1 based indices.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, @Zan Lynx: Tried to implement your suggestions. There are some restrictions to `sizeof` when using multidimensional VLAs. Despite that, it seems to be possible to combine some advantages of VLAs, asserts (without extra fields) and macros.

Comment: @Sam, not clear to me to what restrictions you refer. For the combination with macros, sure, I have a whole set of such macros in P99, http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__VLA.html

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: What I was referring to is, that `sizeof(matrix) == 0` in functions like `internal_vla2Dset()` in my second example, thus, I was not able to determine the size of the first dimension by applying the `sizeof` to the VLA argument only. However, I stopped right there. I'll have a look at P99.

Comment: @Sam, the operator `sizeof` can never return `0` on a valid object. But effectively since the innermost dimension of function parameters is always rewritten as a pointer, you'd have to pass that information to the function in an extra parameter, if you need it. The compiler itself doesn't need it, since index calculations for `A[i][j]` can be done without it.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt : That extra parameter is already in use. Not sure, what I could have done wrong there, assuming, the compiler is right. I'd expect `sizeof(matrix)` to match the (static) size of that pointer at least, but it was in fact 0 and it compiled. In `main()`, where the VLA is declared, it works as expected. What I am missing afte all, is the convenience of retrieving the 1st dimensions of a VLA from a function argument only, what would allow me to use `MAT_SET()` and `MAT_GET()` everywhere, without adding additional parameters, which would defeat the whole purpose of all that tinkering.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt : Solved that issue yesterday. When an (explicit) pointer to a VLA is used, like in your example, `sizeof(*A)` returns the dynamic size of the whole array (rows * cols * sizeof(element)) as desired (GCC 4.8.1).